# Deploying Sinatra app .rb

Tags: sinatra

I know this is probably a stupid question. But I created a .rb file with Sinatra framework and I am not sure how to "deploy" it. When I posted the file on the server I just get a simple text file that reads back my code. It works great when I run it with Sinatra.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just call `ruby app.rb` to run. If your code is all right, that will start webrick server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your web server (Apache?) is just *serving* you with your Ruby script (that is a text, ASCII file) instead of *running* it (that is: instead of passing it through the Ruby interpreter).

Hence:

1. Is the Ruby interpreter installed on your server?
2. Is your web server configured to *run* Ruby scripts (files terminating with ".rb")
       through the Ruby interpreter?
3. And, is Sinatra itself installed on your web server?

Anyway, Ruby applications (Rails, Sinatra, Padrino) are usually deployed to a server using GIT. Have a look at Heroku and Engine Yard.

Also, there are tools specifically designed to help the developer in deploying Ruby applications. Have a look at Capistrano or Vlad and/or Google for "how to deploy a sinatra application".

Answer (score 1):

For Sinatra/Rails/etc, most people use a Webserver (ie Apache, Nginx, etc) AND an Application Server (Thin, Passenger, Unicorn).  For a simple app these can live on the same host.  The webserver manages the incoming traffic and the application server executes the ruby code and passes results to the webserver.

When you execute `ruby app.rb` to run your Sinatra application, you're actually loading up WEBrick which is an application server. Since your development machine is local, you can access it directly at `localhost:3000` or some similar address.

Look into tutorial on setting up your webserver with Thin, it's one of the easier ones to work with.  When/if you outgrow it, then look into Unicorn.